# Delete key 'data' of collection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to remove the 'data' key from my collection in Laravel.
This worked for me, but it removed the other keys that I cared to keep, I just need to remove the 'data' key:

```
return $filteredValues ​​= $collection->values ​()->all(); // I remove other keys inside the objects.
```

My collection return:

```
$records = Item::where('tienda_id',$id)->where('item.nombre', 'like', "%" . $query . "%")->take(50)->get();
return $collection = new ItemCollection($records);
```

**My ItemCollection.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ItemCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection->transform(function($row, $key) {

            return [
                'id' => $row->id,
                'nombre' => $row->nombre,
                'marca_id' => $row->marca_id,
                'tienda_id' => $row->tienda_id,
                'nombre_marca' => $row->marca->nombre_marca,
                'unidad_id' => $row->unidad_id,
                'nombre_unidad' => $row->unidad->nombre_unidad,
                'tipo_cambio' => $row->tienda->tipocambio,
                'categoria_id' => $row->categoria_id,
                'stock' => $row->stock,
                'moneda' => $row->moneda,
                'codigos' => $row->codigos,
                'stockminimo' => $row->stockminimo,
                'stockmaximo' => $row->stockmaximo,
                'impuesto_id' => $row->impuesto_id,
                'primer_margen' => $row->primer_margen,
                'segundo_margen' => $row->segundo_margen,
                'precio' => $row->precio,
                'notas' => $row->notas,
                'imagen' => url('images/'.$row->imagen),

            ];
        });
    }
}
```

My JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 27,
      "nombre": "Nombre de prueba",
      "marca_id": 2,
      "tienda_id": 2,
      "nombre_marca": "marca 2",
      "unidad_id": 59,
      "nombre_unidad": "NIU",
      "tipo_cambio": "3.54",
      "categoria_id": 1,
      "stock": 100,
      "moneda": "$",
      "codigos": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "nombre_codigo": "Codigo",
          "tienda_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2020-08-03T15:19:11.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-06T22:38:02.000000Z",
          "pivot": {
            "item_id": 27,
            "codigo_id": 2,
            "nombre": "66677kj"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "nombre_codigo": "CODIGO 2",
          "tienda_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2020-08-07T20:45:29.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-07T20:45:29.000000Z",
          "pivot": {
            "item_id": 27,
            "codigo_id": 5,
            "nombre": "78877k"
          }
        }
      ],
      "stockminimo": 1,
      "stockmaximo": 100,
      "impuesto_id": 1,
      "primer_margen": "35.00",
      "segundo_margen": "20.00",
      "precio": "5.07",
      "notas": "jkjkkjkkj",
      "imagen": "http://maks.test/images/159692202782450637_121718839341269_2075616741920079872_o.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "nombre": "Aleta de pollo",
      "marca_id": 1,
      "tienda_id": 2,
      "nombre_marca": "marca1x",
      "unidad_id": 59,
      "nombre_unidad": "NIU",
      "tipo_cambio": "3.54",
      "categoria_id": 1,
      "stock": 5,
      "moneda": "S/",
      "codigos": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "nombre_codigo": "Codigo",
          "tienda_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2020-08-03T15:19:11.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-06T22:38:02.000000Z",
          "pivot": {
            "item_id": 28,
            "codigo_id": 2,
            "nombre": "jhjjkj"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "nombre_codigo": "CODIGO 2",
          "tienda_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2020-08-07T20:45:29.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-07T20:45:29.000000Z",
          "pivot": {
            "item_id": 28,
            "codigo_id": 5,
            "nombre": "jkk"
          }
        }
      ],
      "stockminimo": 6,
      "stockmaximo": 88,
      "impuesto_id": 1,
      "primer_margen": "2.00",
      "segundo_margen": "10.00",
      "precio": "100.00",
      "notas": "jkjkkjjk",
      "imagen": "http://maks.test/images/159698573182341068_123146022531884_1345097685962588160_o.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need it to look like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 27,
      "nombre": "Nombre de prueba",
      "marca_id": 2,
      "tienda_id": 2,
      "nombre_marca": "marca 2",
      "unidad_id": 59,
      "nombre_unidad": "NIU",
      "tipo_cambio": "3.54",
      "categoria_id": 1,
      "stock": 100,
      "moneda": "$",
      "codigos": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "nombre_codigo": "Codigo",
          "tienda_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2020-08-03T15:19:11.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-06T22:38:02.000000Z",
          "pivot": {
            "item_id": 27,
            "codigo_id": 2,
            "nombre": "66677kj"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "nombre_codigo": "CODIGO 2",
          "tienda_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2020-08-07T20:45:29.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-07T20:45:29.000000Z",
          "pivot": {
            "item_id": 27,
            "codigo_id": 5,
            "nombre": "78877k"
          }
        }
      ],
      "stockminimo": 1,
      "stockmaximo": 100,
      "impuesto_id": 1,
      "primer_margen": "35.00",
      "segundo_margen": "20.00",
      "precio": "5.07",
      "notas": "jkjkkjkkj",
      "imagen": "http://maks.test/images/159692202782450637_121718839341269_2075616741920079872_o.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "nombre": "Aleta de pollo",
      "marca_id": 1,
      "tienda_id": 2,
      "nombre_marca": "marca1x",
      "unidad_id": 59,
      "nombre_unidad": "NIU",
      "tipo_cambio": "3.54",
      "categoria_id": 1,
      "stock": 5,
      "moneda": "S/",
      "codigos": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "nombre_codigo": "Codigo",
          "tienda_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2020-08-03T15:19:11.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-06T22:38:02.000000Z",
          "pivot": {
            "item_id": 28,
            "codigo_id": 2,
            "nombre": "jhjjkj"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "nombre_codigo": "CODIGO 2",
          "tienda_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2020-08-07T20:45:29.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-08-07T20:45:29.000000Z",
          "pivot": {
            "item_id": 28,
            "codigo_id": 5,
            "nombre": "jkk"
          }
        }
      ],
      "stockminimo": 6,
      "stockmaximo": 88,
      "impuesto_id": 1,
      "primer_margen": "2.00",
      "segundo_margen": "10.00",
      "precio": "100.00",
      "notas": "jkjkkjjk",
      "imagen": "http://maks.test/images/159698573182341068_123146022531884_1345097685962588160_o.jpg"
    }
  ]
```

Thanks in advance for reading me, I hope you can help me solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: I lose the keys and values of "codigos" and "nombre_marca"

Comment: Try the "forget", "unique", '' pull "methods and they also remove them, I just need" data "to be removed.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AppProvider.php` or similar add the following. This will disable data wrapping, for ItemCollections. Thou i would want you to reconsider, if you need to use pagination or meta attributes on your responses, you have no where to put em withouth data wrapping and thats one of the reason it is used.

```
public function boot()
{
    ItemCollection::withoutWrapping();
}
```